# Wine "Compatibility mode must be turned off"

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, wine

Okay so I have a program that I need to run on my Ubuntu 18.04 Laptop called LockedBrowser and I am having trouble getting it to work. I have installed Wine and installed Locked Browser onto the Wine machine after setting up winecfg.

Now, when I try to run LockedBrowser with Wine it pops up a window before starting saying "Compatibility mode must be turned off" and then auto closes.

Now I know this normally pops up when you are running the program in the wrong windows machine, so I tried other versions of windows on winecfg with no success.

Then I thought maybe the exe was made for a 32 bit system so I created a 32 bit instance of Wine and tried it again with the same issues.

After running into that last brickwall, I decided to try to use a virtual machine, which after I setup a windows 10 machine found out the program does not allow itself to be used on a windows 10 machine.

So now I am scrambling to get a remote connection setup with either VNC or Teamviewer from my Ubuntu Laptop to my Windows 10 PC.

Any help on this issue would be very much appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read this and let me know if I can provide anything to help you help me.

Comment: So what is the question ? (1) Getting it to work on Wine, or (2) Getting it to work on Windows 10. For the second one, you may in the `.exe`, Properties, Compatibility tab, set to run this program in a Windows version that it likes.

Comment: I want to get it to work on Wine, that's my main goal. However, if I can't then I would like to use any of the other options that I mentioned in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the Windows version, which for Wine is XP by default.

The application might be made for newer version(s) of Windows, so thinks that you
have set to XP the Compatibility mode for its executable
(in Windows: Properties, Compatibility tab, "Run this program in compatibility mode for:").

You might try to change the Windows version to higher, although the change is only
cosmetic in nature : Wine will report this version if asked but will always work
the same (meaning XP mode for system calls).
So there is no guarantee that this will work.

See the [Winecfg](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg) documentation to find out
how to change the settings for all applications ("Default Settings") or
for a specific application (which overrides the default settings).